# Getting the error as 'Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 4 Must declare the scalar variable "@TotalCount".'

Tags: sql-server

```
Create procedure spgetaveragesalaryAndCount
    @Gender nvarchar,
    @DepartmentId int,
    @AverageSalary int out,
    @TotalCount int out
As
Begin
    select 
        @AverageSalary = AVG(salary), 
        @TotalCount = COUNT(Id)
    from 
        tblemployee 
    where 
        Gender = @Gender 
        and DepartmentId = @DepartmentId 
    group by 
        gender, departmentid
End

declare @AvgSalary int 
declare @HeadCount int

exec spgetaveragesalaryAndCount 
           @Gender = 'Male',
           @DepartmentId = '1', 
           @AverageSalary = @AvgSalary out,
           @HeadCount = @TotalCount out

Print @AvgSalary, @totalcount
```

Whenever I am calling this stored procedure, I am getting an error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@TotalCount"

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use. In your case, a parameter of type `nvarchar` without any length has a length of **EXACTLY 1 character** which typically is *not* what you want / expect.... So just **always** define a length when you use `varchar` or `Nvarchar` !

Comment: @marc_s:Thank you very much Sir:)

Answer (score 2):

You want to reverse assignment in `exec` and use `@HeadCount` in the print

```
declare @AvgSalary int
declare @HeadCount int

exec spgetaveragesalaryAndCount @Gender = 'Male',
    @DepartmentId = '1',
    @AverageSalary = @AvgSalary out,
    @TotalCount = @HeadCount  out     -- here and 

print @AvgSalary,
    @HeadCount        -- here
```

Also, as mentioned by @marc_s in the comments, use length with the varchar/nvarchar declaration. Without it, the default length will be one character.

```
Create procedure spgetaveragesalaryAndCount
    @Gender nvarchar(20),
    . . .
```

Comment: @GurV- what difference does it make in the print statements if you just separate them in two different rows...P.S. I used print twice for the output parametes and it worked..

Comment: Probably nothing and That's not what I am pointing out. I pointed out that you used wrong variable in print

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the declare statement in the @TotalCount int please see the below code,

```
Create procedure spgetaveragesalaryAndCount
    @Gender nvarchar,
    @DepartmentId int,
    @AverageSalary int out,
    @TotalCount int out
    As
    Begin
    select @AverageSalary=AVG(salary), @TotalCount=COUNT(Id)
     from tblemployee where Gender=@Gender and DepartmentId=@DepartmentId group by gender,departmentid
    End

    declare @AvgSalary int 
    declare @HeadCount int
    DECLARE @TotalCount int
    exec spgetaveragesalaryAndCount @Gender='Male',@DepartmentId='1', @AverageSalary=@AvgSalary out,
     @HeadCount=@TotalCount out
    Print @AvgSalary ,@totalcount
```

Comment: :What is the necessity of declaring totalcount again...if I have already declared headcount for storing totalcount already